# Nginx - Including a PHP script on all pages in a host

Tags: php, nginx

Is it possible using Nginx to automatically include a PHP file to all websites? and if so how do I do it?
E.G.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.coom;
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME c:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        include        ../includes/def.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: to all hosts or all pages on the host?

Comment: every page in the host.

Comment: take a look at this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_addition_module.html

Comment: How do I use that module? It says it's not built in by default?